# Get instanceof type out of an array without if statements

Tags: java

Note: This is an abstracted version of my problem as a lot of actual code would probably be confusing and irrelevant to the problem.

I have an array/ArrayList of objects that all inherit their information from another class.

For example

```
class A

class B extends A

class C extends A

class D extends A
```

Objects of class B, C, and D all go into an array of type A.

Now when they come out I want to cast them back to the original type to use a specific method / variable etc. **How can I do this without having to go through a set of *if* statements to try and find out what sort of sub class it is?** It makes my code very inflexible as I have to write a new set of *if* statements every time I add a new class that extends class A. Is there a way to simply return to the exact name of the class that an object is?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This is precisely what polymorphism (i.e. method overrides) is for.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Can you give an example of where you would use such a capability? Also, what do arrays have to do with this question?

Comment: If you want to use a "specific method / variable" for each class, how would you expect to do this even if you *could* "simply return to the exact name of the class that an object is"?

Comment: Essentially in my program I have an object called sprite which has several sub classes that all do different things. They are stored in a sprite array and each time the program is running they have to execute different methods based on what sort of sprite they are. So I iterate through the array taking each sprite out and casting it to the correct type through if statements and running its class specific methods. I just thought there might be a more elegant way of doing this. I don't see how its linked to non OOP design.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Wrap the class-specific stuff into a `doStuff()` method,  declare `doStuff` as `abstract` in the base-class, and then call that on each element of the array.  No casting needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, this is ugly.  You should use polymorphism instead:

```
class A {
    public abstract void doStuff();
};

class B extends A {
    private void foo() { ... }  // Class-specific method
    @Override
    public void doStuff() { foo(); }
}

class C extends A {
    private void bar() { ... }  // Class-specific method
    @Override
    public void doStuff() { bar(); }
}

...

A[] array = { new B(), new C() };

// No casting or conditionals needed!
for (A a : array) {
    a.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: This approach works if you have exactly one "doStuff" logic to implement. It has the disadvantage of putting the "doStuff" logic in the sprite classes; it might be more appropriate to have the logic reside in the client code and let sprites just be sprites. Also, if you later want to add "doOtherStuff" and then decide you also need "doSomethingElse", a multiple dispatch approach will be less of a maintenance problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the name of the class of an object, you can use

```
a.getClass().getName(); // or .getSimpleName();
```

This will work even if `a` is declared as the type of the superclass. Assuming the class structure in your question:

```
A a = new B();
System.out.println(a.getClass().getSimpleName());
a = new C();
System.out.println(a.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

will print:

> B
>   C

**EDIT**

The use case you describe in your comment can be handled in several ways. The most flexible might be a [multiple dispatch pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) (related to the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)):

1. Define an interface

   public interface SpriteActor {
       void actOn(A anASprite);
       void actOn(B aBSprite);
       // etc.
   }
2. Define a method in `A`:

   public class A {
       public void acceptActor(SpriteActor actor) {
           actor.actOn(this);
       }
   }
3. Override this method in each Sprite subclass. Oddly, you can use exactly the same code in each override. This is necessary so that the compiler will bind the call to the correct overloaded `actOn` method of your `SpriteActor` implementation.
4. In your client code, implement the `SpriteActor` interface. Implement the type-specific calls in each overloaded `actOn` method.

Comment: How do you intend to (type-safely) invoke methods (which is what he said he'd like to accomplish)?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - That's what polymorphism is for.

Comment: that's not what I said, what he wanted to accomplish is to invoke a B specific method.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I understand that. What OP wants, though, doesn't make sense. Suppose there was a magic way to automatically convert to the desired type (other than `getClass()`). How would you package it up into a method (specifically, what would be the return type)? One does what OP is trying to do by reflection, by declaring an abstract method in the base class, or by casting.

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't make much sense accomplishing his goal this way.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I added a possible approach to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is all very helpful. Not exactly the solution I was thinking of but it should work! :)